# Linkedin API Request fails with "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Pro (truncated...)" (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, linkedin-api, access-denied

I am trying to retrieve the posts from my companies linekdin page using the linkedin api. I basically just copied the api documentations curl example and fitted it to typo3s requestFatory:

```
$requestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=" . $companyUrnEncoded . "&q=author&count=10&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED";

$additionalOptions = [
    'headers' => ['X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
    'LinkedIn-Version' => '202210', 
    'X-RestLi-Method' => 'FINDER',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken ]
];

$request = $requestFactory->request($requestUrl, 'GET', $additionalOptions);
```

I have been granted the Advertising API und my access token has the r_organization_social permission. I got it throu 3-legged oauth. I am a super admin on my organizations page, but still get

```
Client error: `GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3Axxxxxxx&q=author&count=10&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:  
{"status":403,"serviceErrorCode":100,"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Pro (truncated...)
```

as a response.

I tried removing various headers, using various endpoints and getting all sorts of permissions, but it always ended with access denied or invalid request.

I'm using Typo3 11.

Comment: This is imho not related to TYPO3.

Comment: your communication with the linkedin-Server fails with an authentification error. make sure you have the correct credentials.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ as far as im aware i have all the credentials, to my knowledge all you need is the r_organization_social permission and a user that is an admin at the organization whos posts youre trying to get, or did i overlook something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the linkedIn API. Make sure the request works in another context. try it directly in a browser or in a shell with `wget`. in case of errors inspect the response. otherwise the code of the `requestFactory`